# python loop over multiple lists inside dictionary key (edited)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am a bit puzzled with loop over python dictionary.
One point of inside my script returns data like this :

```
 [u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-ktrx06zhry_traffic_in_14644.rrd']

 [u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax02zhry_traffic_in_14954.rrd', 
  u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax04zhry_traffic_in_14966.rrd'] 
  [] 
 [u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-kyrx01zhry_traffic_in_14717.rrd']
```

But I want to be output like this (Single dict with multiple string data value)

```
{u'GDR': u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-gdrx06zhry_traffic_in_14632.rrd', u'TSA': 
u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax02zhry_traffic_in_14954.rrd', 
u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax04zhry_traffic_in_14966.rrd'}`
```

Are there any ways to make multiple lists into a single dictionary like this?

P.s - I edited the questions a little bit! Thanks

Comment: Dictionaries maintain the key-value pair, but the output you want does not contain the key for last element.

Comment: If you want the output to look like that, okay, but if you want to return a value, it's not a valid python data structure.

Comment: Your input is mapping to single object ? There are so many list types. But all are disconnected.

Comment: yes.. input is mapping to each object!

Answer (score 1):

Lets say `d` is your dictionary.Do this,

```
 for a in d:
     d[a]= ",".join([str(x) for x in d[a]])
```

also can use `map` function,

```
for a in d:
   d[a]= ",".join(map(str,d[a]))
```

Comment: [u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-ktrx06zhry_traffic_in_14644.rrd']
[u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax02zhry_traffic_in_14954.rrd', u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax04zhry_traffic_in_14966.rrd']
[]
[u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-kyrx01zhry_traffic_in_14717.rrd']     
I want to output like {u'GDR': u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-gdrx06zhry_traffic_in_14632.rrd', u'TSA': 
u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax02zhry_traffic_in_14954.rrd', 
u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax04zhry_traffic_in_14966.rrd'}`

Comment: if so, how should i do? sir

Comment: did not get your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
dict1 = {u'GDR': [u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-gdrx06zhry_traffic_in_14632.rrd'], u'TSA': [u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax02zhry_traffic_in_14954.rrd', u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax04zhry_traffic_in_14966.rrd']}

dict2 = dict()
for key, value in dict1.items():
    if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 1:
        value = ', '.join(value)
        dict2[key] = value

    else:
        dict2[key] = value[0]
print(dict2)
```

Output:

```
{'GDR': '/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-gdrx06zhry_traffic_in_14632.rrd', 'TSA': '/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax02zhry_traffic_in_14954.rrd, /var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax04zhry_traffic_in_14966.rrd'}
```

Explanation:

Iterate over the dict items using `for-loop`:

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
```

Check for condition whether the length of value is greater than `1` and if condition successs then using `str.join()` join the elements of list with `,`.
and update the new `dict2` with key and value.

If condition fails directly add the key and `value[0]` to new `dict2`

Comment: @Swe Zin Phyoe: This is tested and worked as your desired requirement

Comment: hey . or other way, my output from function return is like [u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-ktrx06zhry_traffic_in_14644.rrd'] [u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax02zhry_traffic_in_14954.rrd', u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax04zhry_traffic_in_14966.rrd'] [] [u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-kyrx01zhry_traffic_in_14717.rrd'] .

I want to output like 
{u'GDR': u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-gdrx06zhry_traffic_in_14632.rrd', u'TSA': u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax02zhry_traffic_in_14954.rrd', u'/var/www/cacti/rra/r1f-tsax04zhry_traffic_in_14966.rrd'}`

How can I do?

Comment: Do your requirement changed ? I didn't understand what that comment means ? please elaborate. The code which I posted is giving as per your output in question description.

Comment: yes.. the requirement a little bit changed. sorry for this. i will be thankful if you will advice on this.

Comment: Surely I will help you. Please update your input and output separately in quotes